# The navigation pane in file explorer (windows 10) is partially cut off

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

Can anyone help me? I tried messing more with the navigation pane but none of the settings fixed it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hover your cursor very slightly to the right of the vertical scrollbar [the sensitive area may only be one or two pixels wide]. The cursor will turn into a double-headed arrow & you'll be able to drag the sidebar column wider.

[image]